# PowerShell with WiX - Loop through certificate store and remove cert based on thumbprint

Tags: powershell, wix, certificate, custom-action

I have a simple PowerShell script that runs via a WiX installer. As you can see, it takes a thumbprint from PFX file an loops through the cert store and removes it if it finds it.

```
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'

# server certificate path
$serverCertFilePath = "$dataTransferCertificatePath\server.pfx"

# get thumbprint from server cert info
$serverCertInfo = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $serverCertFilePath
$serverThumbprint = $serverCertInfo.Thumbprint

Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\*$serverThumbprint -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

I have tried `$ConfirmPreference = 'None'` and `Remove-Item` with `-Force`

When I run the above two lines from an elevated PowerShell **it works!**

After that I run the same script using WiX installer:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive –ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "Remove-Certificate.ps1"
```

Then I get the following:

> The operation is on user root store and UI is not allowed.

WiX Custom Action calling as follow:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_RemoveCertificate_set"
                Property="CA_RemoveCertificate"
                Execute="immediate"
                HideTarget="yes"
                Value='"!(wix.PowerShell)" -NoLogo -NonInteractive –ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "Remove-Certificate.ps1"' />

  <CustomAction Id="CA_RemoveCertificate"
                BinaryKey="WixCA"
                DllEntry="CAQuietExec64"
                Execute="deferred"
                Return="check"
                Impersonate="yes" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply a fix I had removed **-NoLogo -NonInteractive** while calling PowerShell script in WiX Custom Action:

For **CA_RemoveCertificate_set** custom action value will be **"!(wix.PowerShell)" –ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "Remove-Certificate.ps1"**

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_RemoveCertificate_set"
                    Property="CA_RemoveCertificate"
                    Execute="immediate"
                    HideTarget="yes"
                    Value='"!(wix.PowerShell)" –ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "Remove-Certificate.ps1"' />
    
<CustomAction Id="CA_RemoveCertificate"
                    BinaryKey="WixCA"
                    DllEntry="CAQuietExec64"
                    Execute="deferred"
                    Return="check"
                    Impersonate="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try open a run-as-admin window with `Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe`

Looks like if you can run this with sudo it will execute.